# what is effective approach to set default values using NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have 4 user settings in the app which are independent of each other. I want to check value for each setting using appropriate method of   `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` for each key and if any of the key is not found in user defaults then register the default predefined value.

I do not want to call `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.registerDefaults(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)` every time with app launch , so i am not registering defaults using this method in `AppDelegate.Swift- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with every app launch but i call a method in root view controller's `viewDidLoad()` which runs a custom logic to check each user settings. if all 4 settings already saved by user no call to`registerDefaults()` at all and if any one of settings not saved, call `registerDefaults()`.

Can anyone suggest is there any effective way of doing this or comment on the way i am trying to achieve it ? Will Apple review team approve my logic?

I want to get rid of too many `IF`'s. Below is the logic i have written :-

```
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() as NSUserDefaults

    rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
    speech = true
    language = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.currentLanguageCode()
    defaultLanguageName = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: language)
    bttnEffect = "Pop"

    var defaultSpeechSettings: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["speechRate": rate, "speech": speech, "languageCode": language, "defLanguageLabel": defaultLanguageName, "gender": bttnEffect ]

    var isSpeechRateSettingLoaded = false
    var isSpeechSettingLoaded = false
    var isLangSettingLoaded = false
    var isBttnEffectSettingLoaded = false

    if let theRate: Float = userDefaults.valueForKey("speechRate") as? Float {
        rate = theRate
        defaultSpeechSettings.removeValueForKey("speechRate")
         isSpeechRateSettingLoaded = true
    }
    if let toggleVal: Bool = userDefaults.valueForKey("speech") as? Bool {
        speech = toggleVal
        defaultSpeechSettings.removeValueForKey("speech")
         isSpeechSettingLoaded = true
    }
    if let langCode = userDefaults.stringForKey("languageCode") {
        language = langCode
        defaultSpeechSettings.removeValueForKey("languageCode")
        defaultSpeechSettings.removeValueForKey("defLanguageLabel")
        isLangSettingLoaded = true
    }
    if let effectStyle = userDefaults.stringForKey("bttnEffect") {
        bttnEffect = effectStyle
        defaultSpeechSettings.removeValueForKey("bttnEffect")
        isBttnEffectSettingLoaded = true
    }
    if !(isSpeechRateSettingLoaded && isSpeechSettingLoaded && isLangSettingLoaded && isBttnEffectSettingLoaded) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaultSpeechSettings)
    }
```

Comment: "I do not want to call `registerDefaults()` every time with app launch" Why not? It would be perfectly normal to call it every time. Are you aware that the registered defaults are only used if there is no user-set value? There's no point in checking if there are user-set values before registering the defaults. `NSUserDefaults` already takes care of that for you.

Comment: @KenThomases - Do you mean, i should call 'registerDefaults()' and register all 4 settings in AppDelegate with every app launch instances and simply fetch values for keys in entire app logic without checking user-set value ? My next question is - Does calling 'registerDefaults' each time overwrite user-set value in application domain 'NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()'

Comment: @MohitChaturvedi why don't you just try instead of asking. Yes you will set a default value in case none has been set before. Just go4it

Comment: @MohitChaturvedi, yes, you should call `registerDefaults()` and register all four settings on every launch. The settings you provide via `registerDefaults()` are only used as a "backstop" when no specific settings have been set. The user defaults system uses a layered system of "domains". The registration domain is at a lower layer than the application domain. When you set a value, that goes in the application domain. When you get a value, the application domain is searched first and only if there's no value there does the search continue to the registration domain.

Comment: Calling `registerDefaults()` does **not** overwrite settings in the application domain. In fact, the registration domain is not persistent at all. That's why your app should set it on every launch.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's review team doesn't care if you write sloppy code.

Note Ken's comment about how registerDefaults() only affects return values if no value is set for the given key.

Aside from that, however, extensions are a nice way to tame NSUserDefaults.

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    private static let speechRateKey = "speechRate"
    var speechRate: Float {
        get {
            return valueForKey(NSUserDefaults.speechRateKey) as? Float ?? AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
        }
        set {
            setObject(newValue, forKey: NSUserDefaults.speechRateKey)
            synchronize()
        }
    }
}

// somewhere else:
let speechRate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().speechRate
doSomethingWith(speechRate)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().speechRate = getNewSpeechRate()
```